# Pass Laravel data to Vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm creating a single page application (SPA) that uses Vue Router, therefore it is comprised mostly of Vue components with one blade component that puts it all together using

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

I want to know how I can pass data computed within my controller and pass it to a Vue component. The current way I'm doing it is by exposing extra API endpoints, for example in my controller I have:

```
public function countUsers()
{
        $userCount = DB::table('users')->count();
        return $userCount;
}
```

Then in api.php:

```
Route::get('usercount', 'UserMController@countUsers');
```

this way I can get the data within my Vue component using `axios.get` call to `usercount`.

Is there a better way of doing this? The data seems to take 1-2 seconds to display on the page and I can't imagine having this implementation for over 20 computations I need to do.

I've seen another method where you attach the data into the JavaScript context using the blade template, but I'm not sure how to get that to work for a SPA with Vue Routers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get userCount in your controller and pass it to normal blade file. You can pass the variable in vue like below.

```
<router-view userCount="{{userCount}}"></router-view>
```

then for accessing userCount variable in vue, you can load this variable from props.

```
export default {
  props: ['userCount'],
  name: 'router-view',
},
mounted:function(){
    let a = this;
    this.userCount = JSON.parse(this.userCount)
}
```

for more information you should read the documentation first. It will help you understand thoroughly.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html